# Bigquery Loading CSV File with 'null' text in the columns

Tags: google-bigquery

I have try to upload a CSV file into Bigquery using Google Cloud Client Library. In that one of the CSV file has 'null' text in the columns, while uploading the file Bigquery returns an error message saying "Too Few Columns".

**Sample File Data:**

column1, column2, column3, column4

1, null, 3, null,

2, null, null, null

I have verified the Configuration json sent, it has four Table fields for 4 columns. And error message says 'Expected 4 column(s) but got 2 column(s)'.

Is there any specfic configuration required to handle this scenario?

Comment: What is the schema (type of each columns) ?

Answer (score 3):

If the columns are numeric, then you specify a null with an empty value.

For example, this works.

```
$ echo 2,,, > rows.csv
$ bq load lotsOdata.lfdhjv2 rows.csv c1:integer,c2:integer,c3:integer,c4:float
Waiting on bqjob_r4f71e9aebbf9cb57_00000144acfa7622_1 ... (23s) Current status: DONE
```

Note that in your example above, you would have an extra value in the `1,null,3,null,` line because there is an extra comma at the end. And also note that if your .csv file has a header row, you should use the --skip_leading_rows=1 parameter so that the header doesn't get interpreted as data.

Answer (score -1):

If you have a CSV file with the string "null" as the marker for null values, you will need this parameter on bq load

```
--null_marker="null"
```